# glGetActiveUniformsiv: find uniformIndices[] when Uniform Block Object contains an array of Struct Objects?

Tags: c, uniform, indices

For example,

```
struct A{
   GLint a1;
   GLint a2;
   GLint a3;
};

Uniform X{
    A a[8];
}x;
```

---

```
GLchar* uniformNames[]={"x.a"};
GLuint uniformIndices[1]={0};
```

Now,

```
glGetUniformIndices(programID, 1, &uniformNames, &uniformIndices);
```

-- doesn't return uniformIndices[]? I think I am making an obvious mistake which I am not able to figure out. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got where I was going wrong, to get the indices the names had to be of the form, x.a[0], x.a[1] and so on.